# Передача классу ссылок на интерфейсы реализованные в активити ссылкой на Activity, а не на интерфейсы - стоит ли?

Tags: java, android, activity, интерфейс

**Дано:**

Активити, реализующая **n** интерфейсов. Ссылки на них передаются другому классу (обработчик свайпа `ViewPager`-а, например), через аргументы конструктора.

**Идея:**

Передавать вместо множества разнотиповых аргументов всего один - типа активити, интерфейсы реализующей, во имя сокращения кол-ва аргументов с дальнейшим кастованием ссылки на активити к типу нужных интерфейсов.

**Сомнения:**

Что-то где-то когда-то читал про утечки памяти при использовании ссылок на активити. С другой стороны ссылки на реализованный активити интерфейс ведь одно и тоже, да?

**Вопрос:**

Таки стоит ли передавать классу ссылки на интерфейсы реализованные в активити ссылкой на `Activity`, а не на интерфейсы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше передавать класс, реализующий интерфейс, как интерфейс - это правильно с точки зрения `ООП`.
Когда вы передаете активити, реализующее какой-то интерфейс, например `ClickListener`, в экземпляр класса `View`, то вы передаете туда  именно активити, и все утечки памяти, связанные с этим, будут присутствовать.И не важно, какой тип указан в параметрах принимаемого метода.
Чтобы избегать утечек, нужно обнулять листенер в `onPause()`, и возобновлять в `onResume()`.

Comment: Если коротко, то ваша идея попахивает костылями

Comment: Т.е. если я `ClickListener` передам в `ViewPagerAdapter`, то мне надо ещё к `ViewPagerAdapter`-у прикрутить сеттер для `ClickListener`, чтобы в `onPause` им обнулять ссылки и обратно их назначать в `onResume`? И так будет правильно и никаких утечек?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так рекомендуют. да, утечек не должно быть из-за этого.
есть еще альтернатива. можно листенерами делать отдельные классы, которые не ссылаются на активити, а в них использовать evenbus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus или otto http://square.github.io/otto/    
При правильном их использовании профит будет, и не будет утечек.